# Week of Year Microsoft Flow

Tags: csv, sharepoint, power-automate

I have a flow that grabs data from a SharePoint list every week, and then creates a CSV file from that list. Since it is run every week, I want to name the file `FileName_Week_xx` but I don't see a `weekofYear` epression or something similar when naming the file.

Is there a way to use the other time expressions or create a variable that determines what week of the year the data is being pulled?

Answer (score 0):

I guess You can try an expression step with something like:

```
add(div(dayOfYear(utcNow()), 7),1)
```

Please refer to the below screen show of the flow steps You can create. Hope it helps :)

[image]